# How to generate Swift non-nullable types using OpenApi generator?

Tags: swift, openapi-generator

I'm playing around with Swift code generation and would like to get some advice.

Does `swift5` generator support generating non-nullable types? I've read the docs but I could not find any information about it.

I tried generating some code to figure it out. In spec I defined the `title` as non-nullable. However, after generating the code, the model type does not reflect it - the title is optional. Example:

Spec definition:

```json
[...]
"Teaser": {
  "properties": {
    "urn": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "title": {
      "nullable": false,
      "type": "string"
    }
}
[...]
```

Generated code:

```
public struct Teaser: Codable, JSONEncodable, Hashable {
    public var urn: String?
    public var title: String?
}
```

OpenAPI generator version: `swift5 7.1.0`

Command line command used for generation:

```
openapi-generator generate -i my_spec.json -g swift5 -o ./ --additional-properties=projectName=MyAPI
```